# Scan Identity Cards using Google Vision API

Tags: android-vision

It's possible to read Identity Cards information like name, address birthDate using Google Vision API?
In the documentation, I fount something but I don't know how to use it.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/Barcode.DriverLicense

I checked also the google samples (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision), but I didn't find anything related to Identity Cards scanning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes by using the Google Vision API (TEXT_DETECTION parameter) you can scan an image, get the JSON response and loop through the textAnnotations. I built an ID Checker last month using this service to extract Name, Address, City, State, Zip Code, Expiration and Date of Birth. With lots of regex you can accomplish this with a small drawback that some Dates mistake the / with a 1, so the date would show EXP 04/2212019 or 04122/2019 instead of 04/22/2019, making it tough to get the date but otherwise works 99% of time.

Comment: Hello Friend will you please send me snipshots of project code .

Comment: on device recognition does not work with non latin letters, and accuracy is not as good as cloud recognition

Comment: @RahulKushwaha - how do I send you the snippets? I clicked your profile but I can't seem to find a PM or Message button. This is also done in PHP with basic curl request.

Comment: @EXECUTOR brandon, I also want to fetch these details in my project so that I request you to send code sample to study and implementation.My email id is : rahulkushwaha482@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is in the TextRecognizer api, where you can recognize text and some metadata about it from photo or video stream...
please check it: https://developers.google.com/vision/android/text-overview

Answer (score 0):

There is two options:-

If you are going for paid then you can use CamCard API,ABBYY API. For Free, Use Google Vision Api.For reading text only.Use ABBYY RTR ,I have repository on gitHub. See this link below.Thanks.
 https://github.com/rahulkushwaha482/ABBYRTRDemo